# building Agents in c#

Tags: c#, agents, agents-jade

Is there anything like JADEX or JADE in C# or C++? I am doing a project on agents and so far I can't find anything like JADEX for building BDI agents in C#. Anything in C# that I have found is for doing Agent simulations rather than building agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that it's possible to compile JADE-LEAP on the .Net platform, although I've never done so myself.

Unfortunately, the documentation available online isn't particularly comprehensive. [This thread from 2008](http://old.nabble.com/JADE-LEAP-v3.6-over-.NET-instalation-td18929497.html) is probably the best place to start. There's also [a five-year-old article about compiling JADE on .NET](http://casal.upc.es/~marti23/JadeOverNET.shtml), and [a question from 2008 about compiling JADE-LEAP in C#](http://sharon.cselt.it/pipermail/jade-develop/2008q2/012286.html).

Finally, I suspect that whilst work has been done to make JADE-LEAP compatible with .Net, I don't think that the same is true for JADEX. You'd probably have to port that yourself, or just write your own BDI Agents with JADE-LEAP but without the JADEX extension.

Perhaps it's best to have a go, then post any further queries on the JADE mailing list?

Good luck!